# return values that occur thrice

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------+------+
|naming | year |
+-------+------|
|  A.   | 2003 |
|  B    | 1994 |
| B     | 1996 |
|  A.   | 2001 |
|  A.   | 2002 |
| A.    | 1999 |
| B.    | 1999 |
```

I want to filter out all names that occur at least thrice and for which the year is consecutive. For example, here: A occurs thrice in conseucutive years (2001,2002, 2003) so I want to return A. How can I achieve this in sql?

Comment: *filter out* or *return*?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by joining the table with itself:

```sql
SELECT
    w.naming
    , w.year || '-' || (w.year + 2) AS year_range
FROM words w
    INNER JOIN words w2 ON w.naming = w2.naming
WHERE w2.year BETWEEN w.year AND w.year + 2
GROUP BY w.naming, w.year
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

| naming | year_range |
| --- | --- |
| A. | 2001-2003 |

This query joins a row with same wording and 3 consecutive years. Then groups the consecutive years and keeps only the rows with at least 3 consecutive years.

---

UPDATE:

Given this dataset:

```sql
CREATE TABLE words (
    naming VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    year INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO words VALUES
('A.', 2003),
('B.', 1994),
('B.', 1996),
('A.', 2001),
('A.', 2002),
('A.', 1999),
('B.', 1999),
('C.', 2000),
('C.', 2000),
('C.', 2001),
('C.', 2002);
```

This query will only return namings with **only** 3 consecutive years:

```sql
SELECT
    w.naming
    , w.year || '-' || (w.year + 2) AS year_range
FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM words
        WHERE naming IN(
            SELECT naming
            FROM words
            GROUP BY naming
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 3
        )
    ) AS w
    INNER JOIN words w2 ON w.naming = w2.naming
WHERE w2.year BETWEEN w.year AND w.year + 2
GROUP BY w.naming, w.year
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Comment: can we modify it such that it only returns a name when it occurred ONLY thrice. So for example, if A also occurred in 1999 and that's not consecutive, we should not include it. In this case, the query would return an empty table. Can you maybe add it as an edit in the and?

Comment: @x89 I updated my answer. I did it quickly, it's not very elegant, there is probably a better query.